# Tesseract.js - Not working first time

Tags: javascript, ocr, tesseract, tesseract.js

I have a web page with a simple image **OCR** text.

[image]

I would like to get the text of this image with **Tesseract.js**. It's working fine except at first launch. The following message is displayed and nothing more:

> initializing api (100%)

After reloading it's working fine. I don't know why it only work after reloading the page. If I clear the cache the issue reappears. I use Firefox.

**My HTML/Javascript file**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>QRScanner Library Test</title>
        <script src="tesseract.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="go_button" value="Run" />
        <div id="ocr_results"> </div>
        <div id="ocr_status"> </div>
        <img id="img" src="ocr.gif"/>
        <script>
          document.getElementById("go_button")
                .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    var url = document.getElementById("img").src;
                    runOCR(url);
                });
            function runOCR(url) {
                Tesseract.recognize(url)
                     .then(function(result) {
                        document.getElementById("ocr_results")
                                .innerText = result.text;
                     }).progress(function(result) {
                        document.getElementById("ocr_status")
                                .innerText = result["status"] + " (" +
                                    (result["progress"] * 100) + "%)";
                    });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have downloaded in the same folder all js files: `tesseract.js`, `worker.js`, `index.js` and language package `eng.traineddata.gz`

Comment: Are you sure about that  worker.js, index.js and eng.traineddata.gz file are loading from your local machine not from some online cdn?

Comment: I have same issue have you find solution